# How to create a conditional, reactive pointer-arrow that connects line breaks with CSS?

Tags: css, user-interface, drag-and-drop, tailwind-css, pseudo-element

Any ideas on how can I make the arrow element in the image below?

For context, I have a project I'm working on that utilizes a drag and drop library (VueDraggableNext) and have a line break based on a set width. I want an arrow that renders conditionally when the elements hit the max-width. Starting at the left side of the line break and points at the start of the new line. It doesn't really need to move itself and can really just be a static element itself, but I need to look as close to the image as possible.

Any ideas on how I can do this? I could just have it as a svg that just shows conditionally when there is a line break, but I want the end to grow to the right when there is only one item. Are pseudo-elements the way to go? I haven't had much luck replicating this exact design with those either.

I've made a quick **CodeSandbox** for it that I've been trying to mess around with.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-tailwind-forked-7uxvc?file=/src/App.vue

Cheers!

**NOTE:** For whatever reason, codesandbox is not allowing tailwind to work, but my actual project is using tailwind. I know they just updated the library to include a bunch of pseudo classes, but nothing from what I've read helps in this scenario.

[image]

Comment: I would fire the UI designer. A very stupid approach.

Comment: @Azu can you please give me a bit more information on why that is? Not a very helpful comment to be fair

Comment: Sorry Andy, when I see something like this I get crazy. I'm a UI designer and developer myself. It's easy to draw it in Photoshop or so but how to explain that it's hard to code it. Plus it's meaningless. It's clear that when the row finishes, the items go on the next row.

Comment: That's okay! I totally agree; this is so complex and not worth my time, but I was hoping there was something I missed haha. Honestly, we don't have a designer atm and the project manager asked for something to denote the break in lines. I figured having the index at the top of each item was explanation enough. So you think this can stand alone without any arrows at all? 
Thanks for the comments either way!

Comment: The only reason I see to have such (or better say to have some kind of arrows) is if the user uses a right-to-left language and the items have a specific order, which is the opposite to the language. Otherwise this design is fully meaningless.

Comment: @Azu great point! I've worked on a japanese//English bilingual app before and perhaps that's where I was thinking that this is somewhat reasonable. But this app is English only, so woohoo, less work for me!

Comment: Good luck Andy:)